# How can I remove Google tracking parameters (UTM) from an URL?

Tags: ruby, google-analytics

I have a bunch of URLs which I would like to clean. They all contain [UTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urchin_Tracker) parameters, which are not necessary, or rather harmful in this case. Example:

```
http://houseofbuttons.tumblr.com/post/22326009438?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+HouseOfButtons+%28House+of+Buttons%29
```

All potential parameters begin with `utm_`. 
How can I remove them easily with a ruby script / structure without destroying other potentialy "good" URL parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can apply a regex to the urls to clean them up. Something like this should do the trick:

```
url = 'http://houseofbuttons.tumblr.com/post/22326009438?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+HouseOfButtons+%28House+of+Buttons%29&normal_param=1'
url.gsub(/&?utm_.+?(&|$)/, '') => "http://houseofbuttons.tumblr.com/post/22326009438?normal_param=1"
```

Answer (score 11):

This uses the [URI lib](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) to deconstruct and change the querystring (no regex):

```
require 'uri'
str ='http://houseofbuttons.tumblr.com/post/22326009438?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+HouseOfButtons+%28House+of+Buttons%29&normal_param=1'

uri = URI.parse(str)
clean_key_vals = URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).reject{|k, _| k.start_with?('utm_')}
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(clean_key_vals)
p uri.to_s #=> "http://houseofbuttons.tumblr.com/post/22326009438?normal_param=1"
```

Comment: @steenslag Mine is a tiny standalone script. It gives me `undefined method 'decode_www_form' for URI:Module (NoMethodError)`. What could be the reason?

Comment: @myhd Looks like the method was added in Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: @steenslag Too bad! I’m (still) on 1.8.7 (OSX), but I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: there needs to be an "if(uri.query != nil)" after uri = URI.parse(str). Otherwise, uri.query is nil.

Comment: I like the answer above (the checkmarked one) because this one can screw up foreign characters in the URL. The regex looks like a hack but actually works and preserves the stuff in the URL